# Why do I need to call previous() twice in ListIterator so I can go in 'reverse' iteration?

Tags: java, iterator

We know what `ListIterator` has method `next()` and `previous()` that allow us to **traverse** in both directions. So I made a little program to try it out.

```
List<String> songs = new ArrayList<>();
songs.add("song1");
songs.add("song2");
songs.add("song3");
songs.add("song4");

ListIterator<String> iterator = songs.listIterator();

System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.next());
System.out.println(iterator.next());

System.out.println(iterator.previous());
System.out.println(iterator.previous());
```

What I was expecting is to get:

```
song1
song2
song3
song2
song1
```

But I was **wrong**. Actual result it this:

```
song1
song2
song3
song3
song2
```

Can someone tell me how does this happens? Isn't **cursor** when I am 'in' `song3` literally there, so when I do `previous()` it gives me song **before** that one? How can I finally understand this concept the easy way?

Comment: [ListIterator#previous() Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#previous()) states: "(Note that alternating calls to next and previous will return the same element repeatedly.)" This has to do with the fact on how the Iterator moves the current position when calling `next()` and `previous()`.

Comment: I see, but that doesn't make sense. Why would anyone want to make it confusing like that?

Comment: The `next` implementation returns the current item, then advances. Meaning the pointer points to `song4` after the last call to `next`. `previous` advances first and then returns the value, meaning the pointer goes back to `song3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `ListIterator`'s [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ListIterator.html)...

> ```
>                      Element(0)   Element(1)   Element(2)   ... Element(n-1)
> cursor positions:  ^            ^            ^            ^                  ^
> ```

At the beginning of an iteration, cursor points *before* the first element.

A call to `next()` (1) retrieves the first element after the cursor position and (2) advances the cursor to point after the retrieved element.

A call to `previous()` (1) retrieves the first element before the cursor position and (2) sets the cursor to point before the retrieved element.

---

Lets examine what happens between your 3rd and 4th line of output that is problematic.

State of your iterator after the second line of output:

```
                    "song1"   "song2"   "song3"   "song4"
cursor position:                      ^
```

Now you call `next()` again and output `"song3"`. Your iterator state looks like this:

```
                    "song1"   "song2"   "song3"   "song4"
cursor position:                                ^
```

At this point you call `previous()` and `"song3"` gets printed again. The iterator state after the operation is as follows:

```
                    "song1"   "song2"   "song3"   "song4"
cursor position:                      ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Because as the docs says `next()` gives you the current element AND moves the iterator to the next:

> Returns the next element in the list and advances the cursor position.

This when it prints `song3` the *cursor* is moved just after `song3`, then if you call `previous()` you will get the element just before the *cursor*, hence `song3` again.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if cursor remained on the current iterator? Why advance it and make overwhelm with this example?

Comment: @Stefan not all aspects of the JDK are perfectly designed. This implementation has existed for 22 years. They can't change the semantics because it would break things for people. In practice, I don't think I've ever had a use-case for a bidirectional iterator anyway.

Comment: @stefan this is because it is what everybody does when iterating, ie `t[i++]`, get the current value and move to the next. Then `t[--i]` is the reverse.